# JAVA: Add string (file.getAbsolutePath()) to list (List)

Tags: java, file, list

I have a very simple code:

```
private final JFileChooser chooser;
private List list, fileList;

//some codes

int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(CountdownTimer.this, "Select Files");

    if(returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File[] file = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

        System.out.println("Selected files:");
        for(int i=0; i<file.length; i++) {
            list.add(file[i].getName());
            fileList.add(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("list["+i+"] "+file[i].getName());
            System.out.println("fileList["+i+"] "+file[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }

    }
    else System.out.println("No selection.");
```

I need two lists. The first one will be used for viewing (and removing) purposes while the other
for zipping all the selected files. In zip the files, I'll need each of the file's location and name. But for some reason, the line

```
    fileList.add(file[i].getAbsolutePath());
```

generates an error **"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"** while the line

```
    list.add(file[i].getName());
```

is doing fine. I am using the *List list* for GUI and *List fileList* for the zipping code.

Comment: Have you initialized both list and fileList to point to List objects?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere `fileList` (or `list`) being instantiated like this:

```
fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Tip:** You should seriously look at Java generics and declare your lists like this:

```
private List<String> list, fileList;
```

to make it a typed `List` that can contain only `String` objects.

Comment: If I do that, then I'll have to change fileList to ArrayList<String>. I need my lists to be dynamic. Also, I didn't do that with the other list which is doing fine. Do this: private List<String> list, fileList also generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

`private List list, fileList;` // here is the problem you need to initialize the List.

replace the code with below

```
private List<String> list new ArrayList<String>();

private List<String> fileList new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: It generates an error that says **The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>**

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

```
    private List list;
    private ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
```